# Bash remove a char from line

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file withe following data

```
:1:aaaaa:aaa:aaa
```

and i want to remove the leading colon using bash to be like

```
1:aaaaa:aaa:aaa
```

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/89995/bash-remove-first-and-last-characters-from-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed 's/^://' filename
```

`^` denotes the start of line, so `^:` would match a colon at the beginning of a line.  Replace it by nothing!

Answer (score 0):

```
str=':1:aaaaa:aaa:aaa'
echo ${str:1} #=> 1:aaaaa:aaa:aaa
```

Resources: [Bash string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

Answer (score 0):

As well as sed, you may get better performance for such a simple operation on a large file by using `cut`:

```bash
cut myfile -d : -f 2-
```

You can also extract additional fields this way with other -f values.

If you want to remove the leading colon from data in a variable, such as in a loop, you can also do

```bash
myvar=":1:aaaaa:aaa:aaa"
echo ${myvar#:}
```